# While Collections.shuffle() doesn't throw ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, collections

I'm actually learning collections and exceptions and I can't understand why this works :

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));
for (Integer s : intList) {
     Collections.shuffle(intList);
     System.out.println(s);
 }
```

Reading the documentation, it states

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent
>   modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.

Looking at the source code of Collections :

```
public static void shuffle(List<?> list) {
        if (r == null) {
            r = new Random();
        }
        shuffle(list, r);
}
```

So I take a look at the shuffle function :

```
public static void shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd) {
        int size = list.size();
        if (size < SHUFFLE_THRESHOLD || list instanceof RandomAccess) {
            for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
                swap(list, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));
        } else {
            Object arr[] = list.toArray();

            // Shuffle array
            for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
                swap(arr, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));

            // Dump array back into list
            ListIterator it = list.listIterator();
            for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                it.next();
                it.set(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally it calls the swap function :

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
        final List l = list;
        l.set(i, l.set(j, l.get(i)));
}
```

Does not this modify the current list while iterating on it (or this is because of this line `final List l = list;`) ? I think I'm missing something important.

Comment: I think modify here means add (OR) remove which alters the size of the list, not SWAP.

Comment: It might be implementation specific, but `set` doesn't usually change the `modCount` which runs the whole `ConcurrentModificationException` show..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer lies in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) - emphasis mine:

> (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; **merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.**)
>
> ...
>
> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: **if the list is structurally modified** at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

`shuffle` only calls `set`, therefore it's not performing a structural modification, therefore the iterator doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: “`shuffle` only calls `set`”— in this specific implementation.

Comment: @Holger: Yes, that's true. I think it would be an unusual implementation *not* to just perform swaps though.

Answer (score 3):

```
 for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
   swap(list, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));
```

It's not iterating here, per se; there's no `Iterator` involved.  And in the second branch, it does does all the modification *through* the `Iterator`, which is how you're supposed to do it to avoid a ConcurrentModificationException.